# Tools.DiffFiles returns error <FileName> does not exist or is a directory

Tags: visual-studio-2015, diff

I'm trying to use Tools.DiffFiles in the Visual Studio 2015 Command Window.

As I type in the file names, I'm getting intellisense from the file system, so I know the Command Window has access to the my file system and I know the files exist.

When I execute the command, the error message ", does not exist or is a directory" is returned.

I've tried putting the files in different folders, quoting and not quoting the filename, shortening the filenames to where quotes aren't required, etc. with no resolution.

Great tool, but why can't it find my files?

Comment: I'm getting the exact same thing.  Would love to have an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write the command Tools.DiffFiles be aware to not include a comma between file paths. In other words command definition is 'Tools.DiffFiles path1 path2' and NOT 'Tools.DiffFiles path1, path2'.
In latter case VS try to compare file 'path1,' and 'path2' complaining that it can't find first file.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What eventually worked for me in Visual Studio 17 was entering the full path.  When using the intellisense/autocomplete that the Command Window provides for the path after typing Tools.DiffFiles, it started the path with the project folder I had open, leaving off the beginning of the path, and I met the same results above.

```
Tools.DiffFiles Tmp\logit.txt Tmp\logit2.txt
Tmp\logit.txt does not exist or is a directory
```

But when I started by typing the root mapped drive (c:\ for example), then keep hitting '\' to traverse directories to the file you want, in the project you have open, it eventually worked.

```
Tools.DiffFiles c:\Tmp\logit.txt c:\Tmp\logit2.txt
```

Another thing I noticed was if a directory or file name had a space (c:\My Documents) for example, the intellisense/autocomplete was smart enough to add double quotes around the path, which were required.  If the path had no spaces, (c:\MyDocuments) it left quotes off.  If you try manually typing a path and leave quotes off when it encounters space, it also doesn't work.

```
>Tools.DiffFiles c:\Tmp\logit.txt c:\Tmp\logit 1 copy.txt
c:\Tmp\logit does not exist or is a directory


>Tools.DiffFiles c:\Tmp\logit.txt "c:\Tmp\logit 1 copy.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

enclose the filespaths in quotes e.g. >Tools.DiffFiles "c:\file1.txt" "c:\file2.txt" then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm this bug still exists in Visual Studio 2022. You have to enter the full path of the files you are diff-ing, even though the editor suggests the filename without a path when entering the Tools.Difffiles command.